# Using class to manipulate one variable in loop within function

Tags: python

I'm having a little trouble figuring this one out.  I'm new to Python and doing an assignment for an intro class.  Basically we are using an old assignment in which we calculated the power generated by a bicycle rider and adding code to get the desired output.  Anyway,  this is what I have so far:

```
def powerPerSec():
    M = float(input("What is the mass of the rider in kg?"))
    Mb = float(input("What is the mass of the bike in kg?"))
    V = float(input("What is the velocity of the rider in m/s?"))
    Cfd = float(input("What is the coefficient of drafting?"))
    G = 9.8
    K = 0.18
    Cr = 0.001
    Pair = K * Cfd * (V**3)
    Proll = Cr * G * (M + Mb) * V
    return int(Pair + Proll)
def main():
    print ("The rider is generating", powerPerSec(), "watts.")
main()
```

Now, the next part of the problem is to, "call powerPerSec for 5 different mass values for the rider with the mass increasing by 4 kg increments each time."  The instructions say that all calculations and function calls need to be done in the main function.  What confuses me is how can I do all the calculations in the main function without pretty much eliminating the powerPerSec function?  How can I alter a local variable from the powerPerSec function from within the main function?  Will creating a class do this, and how? The way my prof worded the question is kind of confusing and vague.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

OK so I think I got this pretty much figured out.  I kind of shuffled things around because I had some trouble with looping and inputs.  Here is what I ended up with and it is giving the desired result.  I am not 100% certain this is what my prof wants because the wording of the question is very confusing, but it is working as desired so I am satisfied.

```
def powerPerSec(M, Mb, V, Cfd):
    G = 9.8
    K = 0.18
    Cr = 0.001
    return (K * Cfd * (V**3) + Cr * G * (M + Mb) * V)

def main():
    M = float(input("What is the mass of the rider in kg?")) 
    Mb = float(input("What is the mass of the bike in kg?"))
    V = float(input("What is the velocity of the rider in m/s?"))
    Cfd = float(input("What is the coefficient of drafting?"))
    n=0 
    while n < 5:
        Psec = powerPerSec(M, Mb, V, Cfd)
        n = n + 1
        print ("A rider with a mass of", M , "kg is generating %.2f" % Psec , "watts.")
        M = M + 4

main()
```

Thanks for the tips, folks.

Comment: Your edit looks good, I think it fits the intent of the question. One thing though, instead of using a `while` loop in `main` you should use a `for` loop, e.g. `for n in range(4):` - this means you neither have to initialize `n` nor increment it yourself.

Comment: This is indeed what I tried to tell you in my (deleted) answer. You might also want to print that there will be a lot (or change the first question text. Also instead of n = n + 1 you can write shortly: n += 1. Instead of increasing M by 4 each time, you also can send as argument: Psec = powerPerSec(M + 4 * n, Mb, V, Cfd).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas for the loop portion, I will try that out.  Michel, I'm not sure what you mean by print that there will be a lot. . . are you referring to the mass input question?

Comment: It looks like have answered your question with an edit. You might consider posting your edit as an answer, accepting that answer and removing the edit from your question.